# Does session windowing already shuffle data into the same worker?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My pipeline's simple pseudocode:

```
pipeline
    .apply(KVPair)
    .apply(sessionWindow)
    .apply(groupByKey)
```

My question is: for session windowing to work, does beam already shuffle all data with same key to the same worker? Or it still does map-reduce to collect windows with same key from different machines? I digged into beam documentation but I didn't see how session windowing operates behind the scenes.

The reason I asked is because I know the amount of data in each window is rather small, so I would like to find a way to make sure all of data with same key will end up in the same worker before hand, hence I can reduce the operating time of groupByKey later from shuffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Window transform only configures the windowing for the pipeline; the actual work happens inside GroupByKey.

Your pipeline will do what you want: there will be a single shuffle as part of the GroupByKey transform.